# Why do I have two login popups in Azure AD B2C using Azure AD account?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I created web application (Angular 5 + MSAL + ASP.NET Core) and connected it to the Azure AD B2C. I needed custom flows while signing, so I have to use custom policy. Auth works fine. Then I had to add another Azure AD provider. The deal is that users from AAD and ADD B2C are signing with different behavior.

in general code is following:

```
this.clientApplication = new UserAgentApplication(
  environment.auth.clientId,
  environment.auth.loginAuthority,
  this.authCallback.bind(this),
  {
    validateAuthority: false,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    logger: logger
  }
);

...

public login(): void {
  return this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(environment.auth.scopes);
}

...

public getAccessTokenAsync(): Promise<string> {
  return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(environment.auth.scopes)
    .then((accessToken: string) => {
      return accessToken;
    })
    .catch((silentError: object) => {
      return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(environment.auth.scopes)
        .then((accessToken: string) => Promise.resolve(accessToken))
        .catch((popupError: object) => {
          return Promise.resolve('');
        });
    });
}
```

Firstly I use `login`, and when http call happens I use `getAccessTokenAsync`.

Users from B2C redirected from login, and `acquireTokenSilent` returns access token.

Users from AD redirected from login, and `acquireTokenPopup` throws error, but token is saved to local storage, so after refresh it works. (Error: Refused to display 'http...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.)

Any ideas why it works so?

Comment: The msal log might tell you something useful.  Put it in verbose mode.

Comment: Yep, updated question.

Comment: hmm, I don't see any of the msal log in the question...